# Como hacer para llamar partes de mi plantilla html en django?

Tags: python, django

Quiero llamar dentro de mi vista partes de mi plantilla HTML?

Algo como esto en PHP:

```
$fecha_ingreso= $this->input->post('fecha_ingreso');
```

Pero no se como se hacerlo. Alguien sabe, que me ayude por favor

Comment: Hola user12740, no tengo muy claro qué es lo que quieres, pero aquí está la documentación oficial de Django sobre [las plantillas](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/templates/language/#templates).

Answer (score 2):

Para acceder al objeto POST desde los views debes usar el objeto request que recibe tu view. Ahi todas las variables estan empaquetadas en un diccionario.

```
#archivo views.py

def tu_vista(request):
    fecha_ingreso = request.POST.get('fecha_ingreso', 'valor por default')
```